# Convert flat data to hierarchical class C#

Tags: c#, recursion, hierarchical-data

I am wondering to get hierarchical structure of those class

```
class Tree {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I collect data to list of object of Class Tree

```
List<Tree> tree = new List<Tree>();
```

One of those objects has not parent. And, at the end get smth like this:

```
Name    |   Parent
C:\     |   <null>
System  |   C:\
Prog    |   C:\
Win     |   System
```

What is a better way to convert this data to such class and get only one main Object of Directory Class that does not contain Parent.

```
class Directory {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Directory> SubDirs { get; set; }
}
```

Also, is there some simple way to create list of paths of those object.
Smth like this

```
C:\System
c:\Prog
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Do you have any specific code you can supply to help identify how best to help you?

Comment: Your existing data structure, i.e. `Tree` class, does not provide enough information to be able to recognize the "directory" position. For example, you will have ambiguous results if you had to describe something like "C:/mypath1/sys/prog" and "C:/mypath2/sys/prog", as these are two different "sys" directories.
Are you sure your `Tree` class should be defined this way? I would expect it to contain the full Parent path, i.e. "C:/...", or the Parent Tree instance directly.

Comment: I apologize for the vague statement of the task. "Name" is an identifier, in this case. There will not be several entries with this name. And if I understand You correctly, "sys" folder has only 1 parent folder "mypath1".